# Вопрос по архитектуре. Импорт классов

Tags: javascript, архитектура, модули

Только разбираюсь в программировании, делаю игру змейку. Есть классы snake, apple, renderer, controls и классы-обертки для примитивов (векторы, ячейки матрицы). Вопрос такой, как корректно сделать импорты классов? Примитивы используются почти во всех классах, нужно ли импортировать их в каждый файл конкретного класса? Как импортировать это все в один main.js файл, чтобы все было архитектурно корректно?

Comment: если вы чем-то билдите потм js, то `import/export`. Если нет, то `<script src=".."></script>`

Comment: Я ж говорю, вопрос именно про архитектуру, а не про синтаксис. Как именно лучше сделать связи, какие классы к каким подключать, чтобы было корректно. Изначально все классы были в одном файле и все работало отлично, но это это не хороший код. Теперь классы развел по разным файлам и хочу понять, как сделать корректную архитектуру.

Comment: как архитектура связана с разбиением код по файлам?

Comment: Как именно стоит связать классовые файлы между собой? В этом вопрос